# ngFor dentro de ngFor não funciona

Tags: angular

Estou tentando acessar os dados com ngfor mas não consigo. Como devo fazer para conseguir acessar cada dado com ngfor?

json:

```
    [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Programas",
    "base_Url": "http://uol.com.br",
    "order": 0,
    "programs": [
      {
        "id": 56,
        "name": "Programa 1",
        "base_Url": "https://google.com",
        "active": true,
        "menu_id": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 57,
        "name": "Programa ",
        "base_Url": "https://google.com",
        "active": true,
        "menu_id": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 58,
        "name": "Programa",
        "base_Url": "https://google.com",
        "active": true,
        "menu_id": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Jornalísticos",
    "base_Url": "http://uol.com.br",
    "order": 1,
    "programs": [
      {
        "id": 59,
        "name": "Programa 2",
        "base_Url": "https://google.com",
        "active": true,
        "menu_id": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 60,
        "name": "Programa ",
        "base_Url": "https://google.com",
        "active": true,
        "menu_id": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 61,
        "name": "Programa",
        "base_Url": "https://google.com",
        "active": true,
        "menu_id": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

metodo no service:

```
  list() {
    return this.http.get<Program[]>(this.API)
    .pipe(
      tap(console.log)
    )

  }
```

componente:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Observable } from "rxjs";

import { ProgramsService } from "./../shared/programs.service";
import { Program } from "../model/program";

@Component({
  selector: "app-programs-list",
  templateUrl: "./programs-list.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./programs-list.component.scss"]
})
export class ProgramsListComponent implements OnInit {
  programs: Program[];
  //programs$:Observable<Program>

  constructor(private service: ProgramsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service
      .list()
      .subscribe(dados => (this.service = dados));
  }
}
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" *ngFor="let program of programs; let i = index">
    <div class="col-sm" *ngFor="let programVerdadeiro of program.programs" >
      <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/200/" alt="" />
      <h3>{{programVerdadeiro.name}}</h3>
      <h4>segunda a sexta | 20h25</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: verifica se você esta atribuindo certo a resposta do `subscribe`, porque no seu codigo tem um erro: `dados => (this.service = dados)` você precisa alterar para `dados => (this.programs= dados)` como o @jrr  falou!

Comment: poxa vida...era isso mesmo!

Answer (score 3):

Você esta instanciando `this.programService` ao invés de `this.programs`.

```
ngOnInit() {
 this.programsService 
     .getPrograms() 
     .subscribe(dados => (this.programs = dados)); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo o que entendi você está querendo acessar os objetos do seguinte tipo:

```
...
{
  "id": 59,
  "name": "Programa 2",
  "base_Url": "https://google.com",
  "active": true,
  "menu_id": 2
},
...
```

Para acessá-los você terá que fazer dois `*ngFor`, no exemplo abaixo eu fiz com `forEach`, mas é só adaptar.

```js
const programs =  [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Programas",
    "base_Url": "http://uol.com.br",
    "order": 0,
    "programs": [
      {
        "id": 56,
        "name": "Programa 1",
        "base_Url": "https://google.com",
        "active": true,
        "menu_id": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 57,
        "name": "Programa ",
        "base_Url": "https://google.com",
        "active": true,
        "menu_id": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 58,
        "name": "Programa",
        "base_Url": "https://google.com",
        "active": true,
        "menu_id": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Jornalísticos",
    "base_Url": "http://uol.com.br",
    "order": 1,
    "programs": [
      {
        "id": 59,
        "name": "Programa 2",
        "base_Url": "https://google.com",
        "active": true,
        "menu_id": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 60,
        "name": "Programa ",
        "base_Url": "https://google.com",
        "active": true,
        "menu_id": 2
      },
      {
        "id": 61,
        "name": "Programa",
        "base_Url": "https://google.com",
        "active": true,
        "menu_id": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]

programs.forEach(program => {
  program.programs.forEach(programVerdadeiro => console.log(programVerdadeiro))
})
```

Em Angular acho que ficaria algo do tipo;

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm" *ngFor="let program of programs; let i = index">
      <div*ngFor="let programVerdadeiro of program.programs">
        <img src="https://fakeimg.pl/200/" alt="" />
        <h3>{{programVerdadeiro.name}}</h3>
        <h4>segunda a sexta | 20h25</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**OBS:** depois mude o nome das variáveis, eu coloquei com esses nomes só para facilitar o entendimento.

Comment: não funcionou :( e não dá erro nenhum

Comment: Eu ate atualizei o codigo na pergunta